# HashMap: The addition of new mutable value changes all the existing value to that value

Tags: java, hashmap

I was just making a simple program to calculate the averages from a list of grades in a class. The program takes a user input of scores a student received from a class, average them and put the scores on a hashmap, where the Key represents the course name and Value represents the given scores. However, the issue i am running into is that, with each addition of a key, all the previously put values get replaced by the new values.
The HashMap that  i used is a nested one:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> courseList = new HashMap<>();
```

The input file is in this format

```
Biology Test 30 90 80 Quiz 20 50 80 90 Homework 50 5 10 20 30 40 50
Calc Test 50 100 80 Quiz 20 88 50 30 50 Homework 30 5 10 20 30
```

The first word is the name of the class. Afterwards, the scores received for each assignment are listed out. Where the first number after each assignment represents how much they weigh in the average calculation. So for the first line, the students scores in Biology is listed. They have a Test that weighs 30% and received a 90 on the first test and a 80%in the second. Quiz weighs 20% while homework represents 50%. So for the first line, the program outputs

```
{Biology={Quiz=73.33333333333333, Test=85.0, Homework=25.833333333333332}}
```

This is correct;however, when the program finishes the second line, the averages of the second line replaces the first one. The output becomes

```
{Biology={Quiz=54.5, Test=90.0, Homework=16.25}, Calc={Quiz=54.5, Test=90.0, 
Homework=16.25}}
```

Any idea of how this happens? When i tried to debug, it seems to happen at the point the nested HashMap gets put into the outer one. I was thinking that it might be that the value share a mutable variable, but i thought only mutable keys were the problem? If this is the case, whats the best way to tackle this?

Code for reference:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GpaCalculatorTest {

private static String courseName;
static Map<String, Map<String, Double>> courseList = new HashMap<>();


static void loadCourse(String courseGradeFile) {
    String[] courseInfo = null;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            courseGradeFile))) {
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            courseInfo = line.split("\\s+");
            String course = courseInfo[0];
            Grades.loadGrade(course, courseGradeFile);
            courseList.put(course, Grades.gradeList);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(courseList);

}

private static final String[] ASSIGNMENTTYPE = { "Test", "Quiz",
        "Homework", "Essay", "Final_Project", "Final_Essay" };

static class Grades {
    static Map<String, Double> gradeList = new HashMap<>();

    static void loadGrade(String course, String courseGradeFile) {
        String[] courseInfo = null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                courseGradeFile))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                courseInfo = line.split("\\s+");
                if (courseInfo[0].equals(course)) {
                    break;
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File was not found");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < courseInfo.length; i++) {
            if (Arrays.asList(ASSIGNMENTTYPE).contains(courseInfo[i])) {

                double sumOfGrade = 0;
                int counter = 0;
                for (int j = i + 2; j < courseInfo.length; j++) {
                    if (Arrays.asList(ASSIGNMENTTYPE).contains(
                            courseInfo[j])) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        sumOfGrade += Integer.parseInt(courseInfo[j]);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                double average = sumOfGrade / counter;
                gradeList.put(courseInfo[i], average);

            }

        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    loadCourse("C:\\Users\\john\\workspace\\ideas\\src\\"
            + "gpacalculator\\course_grades");

}

}
```

Comment: `static Map<String, Double> gradeList = new HashMap<>();` means there is only one `gradeList`. So you are adding the same reference, over-and-over again.

Comment: You've only got one `gradeList` object, so all of the courses are referencing the same inner map. You need to create a `new HashMap<>()` for each course.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HashMap storing same values for all Keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400343/hashmap-storing-same-values-for-all-keys)

Comment: Amazing, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggested : the problems comes from the static field.
In fact, according to me, static is even not the real problem.

The real problem is you are using a field as a global variable to share data between classes while you don't need any fields but only change the api of your class.
Of course, doing it with static fields generates often still more side effects and problems...

Here :

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        courseInfo = line.split("\\s+");
        String course = courseInfo[0];
        Grades.loadGrade(course, courseGradeFile);
        courseList.put(course, Grades.gradeList);
    }
```

`Grades.loadGrade(course, courseGradeFile);` doesn't return nothing.
Instead it changes the static field. Why ?
A loading operation should return something.
Just do it : return the `Map` and store it in `courseList` :

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        courseInfo = line.split("\\s+");
        String course = courseInfo[0];
        Map<String, Double> gradesMap = Grades.loadGrade(course, courseGradeFile);
        courseList.put(course, gradesMap);
    }
```

And change `loadGrade()` in this way :

```
static class Grades {

   // remove it : static Map<String, Double> gradeList = new HashMap<>();
    ...
    static Map<String, Double> loadGrade(String course, String courseGradeFile) {
      Map<String, Double> gradeMap = new HashMap<>();
       ...
      return gradeMap;      
    }
```

Comment: this is interesting. In this case, is gradeList removed all together? And does gradesMap replace gradeList as the nested hashmap? I am new to programming as  I am teaching myself everything so I am trying to learn as much as I can haha

Comment: It removes nothing. `gradeList` refers to one and only object and you reuse it as the value of two distinct keys.  Indeed, gradesMap replace gradeList as nested map. But this time only as local variable. Good learning :)